# Is API key a way of Authorization or Authentication?

Tags: api-key

I am using API keys with my web service. I share a key with the client and they send it with every request.

Is this Authorization or Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API key is a method of authentication. [Using them for security purposes is often frowned upon. You can read more about them here](https://nordicapis.com/why-api-keys-are-not-enough/)